# What does 년대 mean?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

I found an anki deck with 1000 most common words (I have to translate them to english on my own) but I couldn't find much information about the meaning of this one. One resource mentioned it means "year", is that true? Are there other meanings?

Comment: It means "(the) ...s" as in the 2000s.

Answer (score 2):

@Klmo's comment is right.

Here, I append some more details.

- (eng) ~ (kor) ~ (meaning)
- 2010s ~ 2010년대 ~ from 2010 to 2019
- 1900s ~ 1900년대 ~ from 1900 to 1999
- 2000s ~ 2000년대 ~ from 2000 to 2099

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit more, this is the same word as 연대 (年代), just pronounced differently because of 두음 법칙 (the initial sound rule). Basically, hanja that are normally pronounced with ㄴ or ㄹ as the initial sound are pronounced (and spelled) differently when the hanja comes at the beginning of a word, as opposed to the middle of a compound. This is why "year" is sometimes pronounced 년 (as in 내년 (來年), "next year"), and sometimes pronounced 연 (as in 연말 (年末), "the end of the year," or 연세 (年歲), the formal word for "age").

In this case, the decade number is being treated as part of a compound word, so it is pronounced 년대 (80년대), while when used on its own, to mean an unspecified era, it would be 연대.